# What happened to QListViewItem in qt4?

Tags: qt, qt4, qlistwidget, qlistview, qt3

I don't do a lot of Qt programming so this may sound like a silly question, but what happened to QListViewItem in qt4?

I have this application I wrote some time ago in qt3. I changed that to qt4 using the aptly name "qt3toqt4" program (all this on a Fedora platform).

Internally it seems to change a lot of classes from QClass to Q3Class (probably to provide some sort of backwards compatibility) and then compile it with qt4. I had some problems with it today (to do with reading stdout from a QProcess, but that aside) and I decided to simply rewrite the application in qt4.

Now for the problem - I use a QListView and to this I add loads of QListViewItems in a tree like structure. Something like this:

[image]

But that doesn't seem to be available anymore in qt4. And I can't find any examples that provide this behaviour either. Is there a way to do this in qt4? To maybe make it more complicated - I used my own QListViewItems (derived from QListViewItem) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widget you are looking for in Qt 4 is `QListWidget` and its item class `QListWidgetItem`. It pretty much corresponds to the `QListView` widget in Qt 3 with a classic item-based interface for adding and removing items. You can subclass `QListWidgetItem` just as you subclassed `QListViewItem` in Qt 3.

Comment: Close. After trying your suggestion for a while I found out that there is also a QTreeView and QTreeViewItem .. and it is those I need. Thanks for pointing me into a semi correct direction ..

Comment: Ah, I read your question in a hurry and missed that you were organizing things in a tree. Sorry. There's no such thing as a QTreeViewItem in Qt 4, but you probably mean QTreeWidget and QTreeWidgetItem?

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete this question. It is QTreeWidget and QTreeWidgetItem that implement this behaviour in qt4.

Comment: QTreeWidget and QTreeWidgetItem - QTreeView is model-based